# TcpClient.Client.Receive() stops getting messages for a few seconds

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, network-programming, tcpclient

I have an application that receives a message, through a TCP connection, every second. It worked great for a long time, but lately im having issues with it.
My TCP client stopped getting messages for 11 seconds (im logging every message's receive time) and after those 11 seconds, I got all the messages in a burst.
The strangest thing is, I checked my network using WireShark and I saw that all the messages were sent when thay were supposed to (one message for each second), and they were all acknowledged too. This probably means that the problem is in the the TcpClient.

I will also mention this - I had been working on Windows Server 2003 for a long time and had no problem, but right now Im working on Windows Server 2008 64bit andMy application is a .NET 4, 33bit application.

Any help?

Comment: You should monitor your thread pool. Actually monitor everything that could correlate with these.

Comment: "This probably means that the problem is in the TcpClient." I find that highly unlikely. More likely, it's in the way you're using it. Without a relevant code example, there's no possible way we could do anything but guess.